# nodejs - memory issue when processing many many json files

Tags: node.js, json, google-chrome-devtools, out-of-memory, puppeteer

I built up a performance test regarding web pages using [puppeteer](https://github.com/addyosmani/puppeteer-webperf) and [puppeteer-cluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cluster). For each user interaction, a chrome dev tools time trace json file will be generated. At the end I got over 18,000 files which size is between 6M-300K.

I also wrote a script to process the json files one by one to find out the interaction's startTime, endTime and duration and generate the final test report. The script is working well with 5,000 files but getting 'Heap out of memory' error with more files.

In fact, for each json file, once I get the data I need (startTime, endTime and duration), I would like to release the memory related to the file as I don't need those variables any longer.

if there is no way to release the memory at run time, is there any way to force my script work within a pre-allocated memory space? It doesn't matter that my post-test script is taking hours to finish its job.

Comment: Instant idea: extract data from JSON via subprocesses (one sub- per file/request/chunk) and kill sub- once you got result. No extra memory will be consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You could use streams to avoid the memory problem.
Something like this should do

```
import JSONStream from 'JSONStream'
import fs from 'fs';

const run = async (file) => {
  fs.createReadStream(file)

  const myData = [];

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = JSONStream.parse()

    stream.on('error', (error) => reject(error))
    stream.on('end', resolve)

    stream.on("data", function (data) {
      myData.push(data.startTime)
    })
  })
  
  return myData
}

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad! There is a defect in the post test script which holds many references to the files.